# Call a function on a div with different borders

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` with a class called 'ball', each edge of the div has a border (border-top, border-left etc) I want to trigger different events with JavaScript when the user clicks on a border on each border.

ex: user clicks on border-top
`console.log('top')`
and so on

HMTL:

```css
.ball {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-top: 20px solid green;
  border-left: 20px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 20px solid orange;
  border-right: 20px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

I know I can trigger events when the user clicks on the div itself, but I would like to, somehow, select these borders with Javascript.

Comment: I think it's best you look into what you can do with a html canvas tag, as @C.Schubert said, this isn't possible with basic html, css and javascript, it would be possible if you implemented some more complex javascript, but I think that would be necessary and would ultimately bloat the application that you're developing.

Comment: You can have a `click` handler on the `div` and then use math to determine whether the click was on a border and, if so, which one, and then dispatch to the function you want called.

Comment: i updated my answer based on your new code ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate this by adding extra elements.

Here is an exmaple (I used jQuery for simplicty but you can easily change to JS)

```js
$('span').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).data('value'));
})
```

```css
.ball {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  font-size:0;
}

span:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  
}
span:nth-child(n+2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  transform:rotate(90deg);
  background: purple;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  background: blue;
}
span:nth-child(5) {
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ball">
  <span data-value="center"></span>
  <span data-value="bottom"></span>
  <span data-value="left"></span>
  <span data-value="top"></span>
  <span data-value="right"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a green "large orb" with a yellow "smaller orb" over the bottom right of that,, no blue, they turn red on hover (not sure which "red" that is...)perhaps edit to use different (although ugly) colors for each portion to make the action and intent super obvious?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss simply because the question got updated after my answer .... check the edit log and you understand why i have done this. ... and the red hover it's simply to show that we can interact with them separately ... i will need to update the answer with the new question now

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed to do.

Comment: In firefox I get red center but "right" on every click outside and the border is all orange.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss strange, it should work pretty well with Firefox because i tested with firefox ... you may have this behavior with IE because of the clip-path support https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: I tested this with a newer version of Firefox and it works - so it was just that older version which happens some times.